# Show that a functions is not $\beta$ Holder.

Tags: real-analysis

Lets define $f^\alpha:\left [ 0,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\;$ by $f^{\alpha}(x)=x^\alpha$

For $0<\alpha\leq1\;$ I have shown that $f^\alpha$ is $\alpha$ Holder.

I want to show that if $0<\alpha<\beta<1$ then $f^\alpha$ is not  $\beta$ Holder.

I tried by proof by contradiction, but I didn't reach anything solid. I am missing the punch-line of this proof. I don't even understand intuitivly why $f^\alpha$ is not  $\beta$ Holder.

Would love to get some help, thanks guys.

Comment: you can try to find a counter example, for instance take $y=2x$ so you can simplify by $x^\alpha$.

Comment: @zwim Could you please elaborate?

Comment: from the suggestion of @zwim, you need to show that for any $K >0$, there exists x such that $|(2x)^{\alpha}-x^{\alpha}| > K. x^{\beta}$, $x$ closed enough to $0$ must do the job.

Comment: yes, $x^{\alpha-\beta}\to\infty$ when $x\to 0$ so there is no $K$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks alot.